# Check if variable satisfies overloaded functions without a call

Tags: c++

I have a code like the following:

```cpp
inline uint16_t byteSwap(uint16_t i) {/*..*/}
inline uint32_t byteSwap(uint32_t i) {/*..*/}

template<typename T>
T byteSwapLe(T i)
{
    #if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
    return i;
    #else
    return byteSwap(i);
    #endif
}
```

The problem with `byteSwapLe()` is that it accept any type on a little-endian machine rather than giving an ambiguous call error.

I need a way to ensure that a variable is compatible with `byteSwap()` overloads even if there is no actual call (on little-endian machines),
thus forcing the user to use an explicit cast when necessary.

I can use a `decltype()` trick:

```cpp
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
return (decltype(byteSwap(i)))i;
```

But maybe there is a less hackish solution that works with pre-c++11 compilers and doesn't require a lot of boilerplate code?

**Update** Another simple workaround is to make a call, but
cast the result to void, so compilers will be able to remove it:

```cpp
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
(void)byteSwap(i);
return i;
```

This will work with pre-C++11 compilers.

Comment: »[...] that works with pre-c++11 [...]«  Probably not.  For such things you need expression SFINAE which only works in C++11.

Comment: sizeof expression is compiled and not evaluated.
`sizeof(byteSwap(i));`
anyway, compiler should be able to remove byteSwap if it proves it has no side effects.

Comment: GCC and clang give the warning in this case, so it still needs the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SFINAE to select a certain overload.  However, this requires C++11 and if no overload is available the error message is meh.

```
// To trigger this example, remove in production!
#define __BYTE_ORDER__ __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename T >
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,uint16_t>::value,T>::type
byteSwap(T i) {
    std::cout << "uint16_t\n";
    return i;
}

template < typename T >
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,uint32_t>::value,T>::type
byteSwap(T i) {
    std::cout << "uint32_t\n";
    return i;
}

template<typename T>
T byteSwapLe(T i)
{
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
    return i;
#else
    return byteSwap(i);
#endif
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t a = 1;
    byteSwapLe(a);

    uint32_t b = 2;
    byteSwapLe(b);

    int c = 3;
    //byteSwapLe(c); // BOOM!
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bLF3fvFkZRre1jx4)</kbd>